# How to get the remainder of division in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to count number of days based on the division that it declared. I need to calculate the number of days and convert it to points. For example, If enter 10 days, then the point should be 3 (3days = 1 point). Is there any way to keep the points as integers and alert the remainder as excess day?

Thanks. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Sorry if I was not able to explain it properly. Here's another sample. User entered 15 days, for every 4 days is equal to 1 point. So it should be 3 points and just alert the days that were not used.

Comment: You can use `modulo` in order to get the remaining - excess - days in your case, if that's what you mean. For example 10 % 3 = 1, or 15 % 4 = 3.

Comment: Something like this? `var res=NumberDays%4  // If NumberDays is 15; shows 3. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
points = Math.floor(days/3);
excessDays = days % 3;
```